# Determinant of block matrix $\Sigma$

Tags: matrices, normal-distribution, determinant

> Let $\bf{X}\sim N_p(\mu,\Sigma)$ with $|\bf{\Sigma}|\neq 0$. Check
>   that 
>   $$|\bf{\Sigma}|=|\bf{\Sigma}_{22}||\bf{\Sigma}_{11}-\bf{\Sigma}_{12}\bf{\Sigma}_{22}^{-1}\bf{\Sigma}_{21}|$$
>   (**Hint:** Note that $|\bf{\Sigma}|$ can be factored into the product of
>   contributions from the marginal and conditional distributions.)

First thing I noticed is that I should write $\bf{\Sigma}$ as block matrix
so
$$\bf{\Sigma}=\begin{matrix}| \Sigma_{11}& \Sigma_{12}|\\ |\Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_{22}|\end{matrix}$$
(not write the bold). I made some research here and fount it [Proofs of Determinants of Block matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1905652/proofs-of-determinants-of-block-matrices) , so if $\Sigma_{11}$ is invertible I could get the result, but there is no guarantee about it. Anyone can give me some light about the hint given, not understood it.

Comment: The main tool here is **Schur's complement**. See (http://www.colorado.edu/engineering/CAS/courses.d/IFEM.d/IFEM.AppP.d/IFEM.AppP.pdf). Of course $\Sigma_{11}$ has to be invertible, but it is seldom an issue. Moreover, in the context of probability applications, if it wasn't invertible, we should have degeneracy problems...